# Check if paths and files exists. Where to store strings?

Tags: python

I want to check if various files and paths exist in my python code like:

```
if path.exists(f'{self.variable}/Desktop/folder1/folder2/filename'):
    print("something")
```

I have multiple long paths and if one path does not exist I want to create it etc.

Should I keep all the string  on the place where I use them or store them in variables when I initialize my class.

None of them is really reused they are all used once.

What is the best practice?

Comment: You can store the paths in a text file

Comment: that would really hard to read, i think they should be in the code for readability but is it ok to leave them in place or store them in variables?

Comment: It really depends on what you want your code to do in the first place. Without further knowledge, I'd say you can store the paths in a `paths_to_validate` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.makedirs` makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.  Pass `exist_ok=True` to ignore directories that already exist.

```
os.makedirs('/path/to/directory', exist_ok=True)
```

This is equivalent to `mkdir -p` on a Unix system.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import path
def wasCreatedIfNotExist(location):
    if path.exists(location):
        return False
    else:
       os.mkdir(location)
       return True

path_list = ["/var","/etc", "/home/x"]
for location in path_list:
   wasCreated = wasCreatedIfNotExist(location)
   print(location + " -> wasCraeted: " + (wasCreated))
```